# Can a polynomial of degree 2 be non quadratic

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

By wikipedia:
In algebra, a quadratic function, a quadratic polynomial, a polynomial of degree 2, or simply a quadratic, is a polynomial function in one or more variables in which the highest-degree term is of the second degree.

But the below polynomial is also of degree 2 and non quadratic:

xy + x + y

So, why do we say, polynomial of degree 2 is a quadratic function?

Comment: Compare these two: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

and 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial

Comment: The degree of a term (we call it a monomial) is the *sum* of the exponents of all variables. Since $xy=x^1y^1$, we have degree $1+1=2$. Quadratic polynomials are *exactly* the polynomials of degree two, there are no exceptions by definition.

Comment: Read Wikipedia artcile [Quadratic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function) ".. but the highest degree term must be of degree 2, such as $x^2, xy, yz$, etc. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say it because of conventions. It makes sense.

I think the biggest reason why is that whether a function on the plane is quadratic shouldn't depend on exactly which coordinate axes we impose on the plane. For instance, if I didn't like your $xy$-axes, and instead wanted $uv$-axes $45^\circ$ to yours (say my point $(1,0)$ is at your $(1,1)$ and my point $(0,1)$ is at your $(-1,1)$), then my expression for the *same function* would be
$$
\frac14u^2-\frac14v^2 + u
$$
which clearly has quadratic terms.

Answer (score -1):

$xy+x+y =0$ (I added the = 0 to make your question complete) is not of degree two for x.

Rearranging: $y=\frac{-x}{x+1}$

Thus it is not quadratic.

Comment: Most certainly it has to be viewed as a polynomial in the two variables $x$ and $y$ where it is indeed of degree two.

Comment: Adding '= 0' is unnecessary, as the question is about the polynomial, not an equation. And it actually **is** of degree 2 – the $xy$ term has two variables in first power: $xy=x^{\color{red}1}y^{\color{red}1}$ hence its degree $\color{red}1+\color{red}1=2$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes.